# iPhone coords and onclick with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iphone

I have a couple of js queries.

Onclick isn't working on iPhones although its fine elsewhere.

JavaScript:

```
document.onclick = function(){newTarg(speedS)};
```

Any ideas on way round this, thinking maybe onchange but not sure how best to implement?

Also I am trying to get coordinates of the touch please help, so far code below.

JavaScript :

```
event = window.event;   
xTarg = event.clientX;
yTarg = event.clientY;
```

Comment: window.event is IE browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click events don't work on iOS use the touchstart, touchmove and touchend events to work out if the users tapped the screen.

JavaScript below:

```
   var tap = true;
   document.addEventListener('touchstart',function(e) {
      tap = true;
   });
   document.addEventListener('touchmove',function(e) {
     tap = false;
   });
   document.addEventListener('touchend',function(e) {
      if(tap) {
         //users tapped the screen
      }
   });
```

For user coords use the changedTouches object to see where on the page the user has tapped.

JavaScript:

```
   var tap = true;
   document.addEventListener('touchstart',function(e) {
      tap = true;
   });
   document.addEventListener('touchmove',function(e) {
     tap = false;
   });
   document.addEventListener('touchend',function(e) {
      if(tap) {
         var touch = e.changedTouches[0];
         var pageX = touch.pageX;
         var pageY = touch.pageY;
      }
   });
```

hope that helps